# New to Java, trying to code Bottles of Beer song

Tags: java, methods, constructor

I am struggling to cope with Java in University and I'm not sure why. Previously I had done a semester of C Programming to which I found was very easy, but I can't seem to wrap my head around Java. I'm currently in my fourth week of Java programming and I'm trying to code a Bottles Of Beer song program to my lecturers standards and I don't quite understand what he's asking me to do. I was able to code this my way fairly quickly however I don't quite understand my lecturers instructions.

```
public class BottlesOfBeer
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int beerNum = 99;
        while (beerNum > 0)
    {
        System.out.println(beerNum + " bottles of beer on the wall " + beerNum + " bottles of beer. Take one down. Pass it around. " + (beerNum - 1)+ " bottles of beer on the wall.");
        beerNum--;
    }
    System.out.println("No more bottles of beer on the wall"); 
}
```

Lecturers Instructions:

- 1. Create a Program called BottlesOfBeer.java.  Which prints out the famous and annoying Bottles of Beer song.
- 2. The constructor should accept the starting number of bottles as an integer and store it as a field.
- 3. Create a method called startDrinking, which simply loops backward from the starting number all the back down to 0 printing out each line of the song.
- 4. Create a driver main method which creates the BottlesOfBeer object and runs it by calling the startDrinking method.

Comment: Which part are you stuck on? What's your question?

Comment: @shmosel What is the purpose of adding the number of bottles to the constructor, how do I bring that value into startDrinking, and how do I call the method startDrinking into the main function to print out those lines

Comment: Your first two points are covered by [Providing a constructor to your class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) and [Passing information to your constructor/methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html), [Understanding class members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) may also help

Comment: In fact, most of the requirements can be answered via [Classes and objects tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for the links, I will be sure to have a read through before naively copy and pasting the answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on your way. Try something like:

```
public class BottlesOfBeer
{
    int beerNum; // instance field

    // Constructor: accept number of beer bottles
    private BottlesOfBeer(int beerNum)
    {
        this.beerNum = beerNum; // Store in instance field
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         // Assume first arg contains the number of bottles
         BottlesOfBeer beer = new BottlesOfBeer(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
         beer.startDrinking();
    }

    public void startDrinking()
    {
        while (beerNum> 0)
        {
             System.out.println(beerNum + " bottles of beer on the wall " + beerNum + " bottles of beer. Take one down. Pass it around. " + (beerNum - 1) + " bottles of beer on the wall.");
             beerNum--;
        }
        System.out.println("No more bottles of beer on the wall");
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't call a `while-loop` "having a go" based on the requirements.  Feed a man, teach a man :P

Comment: This is actually an exercise from the first week, sort of embarrassing but thanks so much for your help!